# in C++ using atof to convert string to decimal not working

Tags: c++, string, atoi, atof

I'm trying to convert the string variable passed by reference to a decimal. When I put in a string in quotes using atoi it works, but not with a string variable. What should I do instead?

```
void stringDecision(string& assembledString) {

double convertedString; // conversion to double

// remove unary + operator because it's unnecessary
if (assembledString[0] == '+' && assembledString.length() > 1)
{
    assembledString.erase(0, 1);

    cout << assembledString;

    convertedString = atoi(assembledString);


}

else
{
    cout << "I'm an operator " << assembledString;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you show a code example of when it is failing?

Comment: it says no suitable conversion from string to const char exists

Comment: Does this really work when you pass a string in quotes? You are using atoi() and not atof(), thus converting it to an integer instead of a double.

Comment: You should pass `std::string const &assembledString` and use `assembledString.substr(1)` instead of `.erase()`

Comment: I made a mistake when posting the code. I did atoi to see if the same result would happen as when I used atof. I did mean to post the version with atof.

Answer (score 5):

You need [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)<sup>1</sup>

```
convertedString = std::stod(assembledString);
```

Note that you *could* also use `std::atof`, passing it `assembledString.c_str()`. But `std::atoi` would make little sense here.

---

<sup>1 Besides the fact that `atoi` is for converting to integer, not double</sup>

Comment: Thanks! You are the real MVP!